# Meta viewport bugged in Safari iOS7?

Tags: css, mobile-safari

I have a strange issue with a website that doesn't display the right way in Safari on iOS7. Somehow the viewport isn't set correctly as it looks way too small on the screen as it doesn't use the 320px viewport but the larger native resolution of the screen. It does looks fine however with Chrome or on Internet Explorer Mobile.

This is the default meta viewport setting that I use all the time without a problem except for this specific website:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Is there anyone else who recognizes this behavior or know how to fix this?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `.0` from `1.0`. I don't think it should be there.

Comment: Changed it to 1 but with no result unfortunately.

Comment: I have this same problem, specifically in landscape. The height is around 20 pixels off. Is this your same issue? https://github.com/headjs/headjs/issues/261

Comment: No, in the end it was a tiny little typo in the markup...